# Link resource in mysql is being tempermental

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can the same mysql resource be used for multiple queries?

```
 $queries=array($q1, $q2);
 $link=mysql_connect(...);
 mysql_select_db(...);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($queries); $i++) {

      echo "Link is of type " . gettype($link) . "<br />";

      if(is_resource($link)) {
           mysql_query($queries[$i], $link);
      } else {
           echo "Did not execute query. <br/>";
      }
 }

 disconnect($link);
```

Output:

```
link is of type resource
Successfully executed query
link is of type resource
Did not execute query.
```

EDIT: I wanted to point out from the output that the first query executes but the second does not. In between, there is no change to the link. How the queries execute kinda doesn't matter, either (IMHO).

EDIT 2: My exact code below:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", ........);
mysql_select_db(....);

for ($row = 0; $row < $numRows; $row++) {
    if (($query = buildQuery($mainArr, $rowArr, $row)) === null) {
        echo "Error - could not build query. <br />";
        return;
    }

    echo "Link is of type " . gettype($link) . "<br />"; 

    if (is_resource($link)) {
        if ((mysql_query($query, $link))) {
            if($debug) {
                echo "Successfully executed query <br />";
            }
        } else {
            if ($debug) {
                echo "This comes up when row is " . $row . "<br />";
                echo "Link is of type " . gettype($link) . "<br />";
                echo "Datawrite failed - " . $query . "<br />";
                echo "the official line is " . mysql_error($link) . "<br />";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Did not execute query <br />";
    }
}

disconnect($link);
```

Comment: What is the result of the second query?

Comment: You misspelled $querries in your for loop. Should be $queries.

Comment: which mysql resource are you referring to? the `$link`?

Comment: @Dirk Referring to $link, yes.

Comment: @AJ The second query does not execute, as you can see from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iteration of the `for` loop contains a call to `buildQuery()` (not shown here). Does it affect $link in some way, or change the value of $debug?

Additionally, your loop references $numRows, which is not defined here. How many times does the loop execute?

Comment: Executes twice. Inside buildQuery, there is a reference to $link. Why would this change $link if $link is defined there within that function, and independently here within this function?

Comment: @BlackSheep: Resources do not operate like other variables. They are identifiers to open files, image canvases, or (in this case) database connections. Resources are persistent, so any operation on the resource identifier will affect the resource globally.

Answer (score 2):

You mis-spelled `$querries` in your `for` loop. It should be `$queries`.

Comment: I fixed this in the example. Like I said, this is just a simplification of my code.

Comment: @BlackSheep: We can't troubleshoot code that we can't see. The code you posted would not cause the problem you described. Please post the real code for better results.

Comment: @George I don't mean to be an ass, but this basically is my code. The only difference is that before the echo statement, I have a bunch more crap that executes just fine and is related to building the queries. There is no mention of $link in that code segment.

Comment: @BlackSheep: Here's the rub: According to the code and output you posted, gettype() says $link is a resource, and the very next line says it isn't. That just doesn't happen. Something else (not posted here) is changing $link.

Comment: @George here is my code after some abstraction. I really do have the output above.